# Populating HashMap with for loop in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to populate **LinkedHashMap** with for loop in order to use it in my **jsf** page but "**put**" method of hashmap overwrites the values that is held in hashmap when the new "**put**" method is fired.

The method is like that;

```
public static List<String> valuesOfEnum() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Map<String, Object> newArray = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        List<String> jsonObj = new ArrayList<String>();
        String json = null;
        for(LimanTipi limanTipi : values()){
            newArray.put("id", limanTipi.getId());
            newArray.put("value", limanTipi.getValue());
            json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(newArray);
            jsonObj.add(json);
        }
        return jsonObj;
    }
```

Here's the jsf code;

```
<f:selectItems value="#{denizlimaniViewController.limanTipleri}" var="limanTipleri" itemValue="#{limanTipleri.id}" itemLabel="#{limanTipleri.value}"/>
```

With this method, I convert the hashmap into list as I couldn't populate the hashmap properly but this is not what I want because I can't use this list in `<f:selectItems>`.

I need to use **itemValue** and **itemLabel** representing "**id**" and "**value**" properties in hashmap.

Is there a way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Each key must be different, use newArray.put(limanTipi.getId(), limanTipi.getValue());

Comment: So put method doesn't overwrite if each key is different, right? @MartinSpamer

Comment: what is this `limanTipleri`? is this the `map` `newArray`?

Comment: @N. Doye The main problem is every time `id`, `value` keys are overwrite(that are given hard coded and after for loop execution only two key are there in map `id`  & `value` and the map contain the last overwrited value). You have to create distinct key for very `value(limanTipi.getValue())` value. You have to create your map something like that `Map<limanTipi.getId()(datatype return by method),limanTipi.getValue()datatype return by method)>  map`

Answer (score 1):

Key get's overwritten because you always have keys as `id` and `value`. Modify your code like below:

```
for(LimanTipi limanTipi : values()){
            newArray.put(limanTipi.getId(), limanTipi.getValue());
            json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(newArray);
            jsonObj.add(json);
        }
```

***EDIT:***

Hope `limanTipleri` is the map `newArray` itself. Then you need to modify your code like below:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{denizlimaniViewController.limanTipleri.entrySet()}" 
               var="limanTipleri" 
               itemValue="#{limanTipleri.key}" itemLabel="#{limanTipleri.value}" />
```

Comment: Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [value] not found on type [java.lang.String]
This exception is thrown. May be it would be better if I add jsf codes to my question